# Using external diff tools with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff, examdiff, kdiff3

Anyone know how integrate ExamDiff with Mercurial?  I have KDiff3 set up but couldn't figure out how to set up ExamDiff.

---

**Update**: Per accepted answer, this .hgrc config worked:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.examdiff = C:\Program Files\ExamDiff Pro\ExamDiff.exe
```

Can run ExamDiff with the comand `hg examdiff`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with [the Extdiff extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension).